# Generate a UUID in python but exclude specific characters

Tags: python, uuid

I need to create a software license key generator for a client and they would like to exclude characters that resemble each other to avoid confusion in case someone decides to type theirs in.  I was looking at just using the python UUID package but there doesn't seem to be an inherent way to exclude specific characters.

I was thinking of just saving it as a string and replacing any "o" character with a "%" or something.  Is there a better way to do this or a reason not to do this?

Comment: If your whole goal is to create a UUID for a database then I would keep it as is but if you are just generating a "hash" type unique ID I would consider doing a password type random generator for it to meet your criteria

Comment: **1.** Show some code. Otherwise this question is too broad and/or opinion based. **2.** The typical "confusing character groups" don't occur together in UUIDs. Example: `0` exists but not `o` or  `O`. Similarly for `1`, `I`, `l` - only `1` exists for UUIDs. `5` exists, `S` does not. `3` and `E` are not ambiguous. **3.** UUIDs are 32 characters long, it's cruel to make a user type that in. Maybe just chop it down to the first 16 or 20 and put a hyphen every 4 chars, so it looks like: `0123-4567-89ab-cdef`. (Also, using only a partial uuid increases the chances that it's no longer _unique_.)

Comment: And you can add in the 'check for ambiguous characters' with each generated UUID. But keep in mind, it's also highly likely that if you have too many exclusions, you may wind up with extremely long-running or infinite loops to generate just one UUID which satisfies the requirements. A replacement-character may be more practical but realise that `%` and `#` etc are not easy for all users. Do something obvious like replace `0` with `K` and `1` with `Y`, etc.